# Why using padding wouldn't help in increasing touch area of a View

Tags: android

I have a view (red circle).

I tend to increase its touch area, by using `padding`. I avoid using `margin`, as it wouldn't help in increasing touch area.

### layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <View
        android:paddingStart="36dp"
        android:paddingLeft="36dp"
        android:paddingEnd="36dp"
        android:paddingRight="36dp"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="36dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="36dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

### circle.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">

    <solid
        android:color="#ff0000"/>

</shape>
```

[image]

However, as you can see, the touch area of the red circle is not enlarge still?

May I know why is it so? Is there any easy way I can increase the touch area of custom view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your padding is not affecting the View size and even if it was, the android:background covers ALL View space.

There's two alternatives:
Use a ImageView instead and android:src in place of android:background. The src will be the content and padding will be applied outside of it, while background will cover ALL view space.

Or add padding at the drawable.xml with the appropriate tags and attributes.

---

### Update from OP

Using `ImageView` solved my problem

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="104dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:paddingStart="36dp"
        android:paddingLeft="36dp"
        android:paddingEnd="36dp"
        android:paddingRight="36dp"
        android:src="@drawable/circle"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="36dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="36dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Missed the point: dimensions are specified exactly in `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height`.

Comment: Did not, the question is about padding, cause the View has fixed size it is not being affected

Comment: Tell me, how the view can respect 36+36 padding when it's also being explicitly told that its width and height is supposed to be 32dp.

Comment: ANY SIZE it have, the android:background will cover all space. The size is not the problem.

Comment: Adding padding to the drawable will not do anything *because the view is set to be exactly 32x32 dp*. `However, as you can see, the touch area of the red circle is not enlarge still?` Whether OP wants to add padding around the red circle or inside it is irrelevant. The view (and its touch area) won't grow if the view's size is exactly set. Do we have an understanding on this?

Comment: Don't you think he don't know that? He want to increase the touch area, not the drawable area.

Comment: @CheokYanCheng Using ImageView did absolutely nothing, you increased the width to 104dp. Feel free to change it back to `View` it will still work.

Comment: @EugenPechanec it will just enlarge the background within, not the View, I tested before adding this answer, sorry extending this discussion.

Comment: No. It wouldn't work. Using `ImageView` is the key of solution. Hope @MarcosVasconcelos can expand his answer, on why it works. Thank you.

Comment: I didn't notice you were looking for only horizontal padding. In that case ImageView really is the easier option.